# Short novel with two men and a woman on a spaceship; one of the men abuses the woman

Tags: story-identification, novel

It is a short novel, with a red cover (I think).

Two guys and a girl (who is kidnapped and held unwillingly) are aboard a spaceship. One of the guys is evil and abuses her. The story takes place mostly on the one ship.

It's written in alternating points of view. It is a short book and a quick read.

I want to say that it was written by a well-known author, but that the story was a bit unusual for the writer.

Comment: My impulse is to suggest Piers Anthony's *Bio of a Space Tyrant* because it was uncharacteristically full of sex for him at the time and it does involve a female character who gets abused, albeit by space pirates, but I've never actually read the book series, so I cannot directly comment.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it...there may be sexual overtones in the story, or episodes but it's mostly about the protagonist's struggle with what's going on (I think).

Comment: How does the story end?  No need to protect spoilers; anyone who can answer has already read it.

Comment: Not a novel, but could it be Fred Saberhagen's "What T and I Did"?  Prisoners are held aboard a sentient "Berserker" ship.  The evil guy "T" is split into two personalities when a surgeon divides his corpus callosum to treat a brain injury.  The story is available online here: http://alfalib.com/book/read/id/90563

Comment: Sounds like the first book of Stephen R. Donaldson's Gap series, The Gap into Conflict: The Real Story. Read the series a long time ago, but I do remember the first book was quite short, the others were much longer.  Here's the wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Real_Story

Comment: I was thinking James Tiptree, Jr.'s "With Delicate Mad Hands", but I seem to have lost my copy of "Out of the Everywhere", the collection that it's in. There's no pirates, just some really awful male crew. The story didn't have a lot of reprints, so it's hard to find now. There's more info on this link: http://randomalex.net/2011/07/15/tiptree-book-club-with-delicate-mad-hands/

Comment: @FuzzyBoots "uncharacteristically"?

Comment: @ChrisSunami: At the time, he was largely known for his Xanth novels, which were relatively clean.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Well, they definitely weren't explicit, but I don't know if that makes them "clean". :D  Wasn't there one actually named "[The Color of Her...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Color_of_Her_Panties)"?

Comment: @ChrisSunami
Yes. Which was one of the later ones after Piers Anthony got annoyed at how the Xanth books were being classified as children's literature and decided to end the Adult Conspiracy. Before that, it was more a matter of winks and nods. The other one that most people remember is *Firefly*. Oh goodness, *Firefly*... the book where I really started understanding that Piers Anthony has an unhealthy obsession with young female sexuality.

Answer (score 4):

This may be *The Gap into Conflict: The Real Story* by Stephen Donaldson. The cover was mostly red or red/orange - like an explosion.

To quote Wikipedia:

> On the way back to Com-Mine, Angus activates Morn's zone implant, allowing him to repeatedly rape and abuse her. Unwittingly, he also starts to form an emotional attachment to her.
>
> Back at the station, Morn makes contact with another pirate — Nick Succorso, captain and owner of the ship Captain's Fancy, who she sees as a potential rescuer. She aids Nick in framing Angus for stealing station supplies, and Angus is arrested. Before he is taken away, though, Angus gives Morn the remote control to her zone implant, in exchange for her silence. With the control in her possession, Morn is effectively a superwoman and is able to disregard fear, pain, or fatigue; but by accepting the control she is also complicit in Angus' crime against her.
>
> Morn leaves with Nick in his ship. Nick, however, turns out to be every bit as nasty as Angus.

Comment: Does it satisfy the other criteria?

Comment: Not as I see it:  it is told exclusively from Angus Thermopyle's POV; and, aside from being one of his few spacefaring stories, isn't all that uncharacteristic of his writing.

Comment: It's also long.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be EE Smith's *The Skylark of Space*?

DuQuesne and Perkins kidnap Dorothy, Seaton's fiancée, and take her into space. At one point Perkins attacks Dorothy but DuQuesne tells him to cut it out.

Seaton and Crane set out in pursuit and the next few  chapters alternate between the two ships.

The only difference I can see is that they have another woman, Perkins' ex-Secretary, with them. But she plays a smaller part and could have been overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly 'Think Blue, count two' by Cordwainer Smith.
Available here in Project Gutenberg
https://gutenberg.ca/ebooks/smithcordwainer-thinkbluecounttwo/smithcordwainer-thinkbluecounttwo-00-h.html